# How to establish $\lim\limits_{r\rightarrow 0}\int_C f(z)dz=i\lambda(\theta_2-\theta_1)$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I got stuck in it. Please help me.

Let $\lim\limits_{z\rightarrow a}(z-a)f(z)=\lambda$ and let $C$ be the arc $\theta_1\leq \theta\leq \theta_2$ of the circle $|z-a|=r$. Prove that $\lim\limits_{r\rightarrow 0}\int_C f(z)dz=i\lambda(\theta_2-\theta_1)$.

Can you please tell me how to proceed in this one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you need to note that $a$ is a simple pole of $f$, then $f$ is analytic around $a$, thus it can be written as
$$
f(z)=\frac{b_1}{z-a}+h(z)
$$
where $b_1=\text{Res}(f,a)$, and $h$ is analytic, hence
$$
\int_{C}f(z)dz = \int_{C}\frac{b_1}{z-a} dz + \int_{C}h(z)dz
$$ 
Expressing $C$ in parametric form, we have $C(\theta)=a+re^{i \theta}$ with $\theta \in [\theta_1, \theta_2]$, therefore for all $r>0$
$$
\int_{C(\theta)}\frac{b_1}{z-a} dz = b_1 \int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2} \frac{ire^{i\theta}}{re^{i\theta}}=i b_1(\theta_2-\theta_1)
$$ 
Now, since $h$ is analytic, then around $a$ it must be bounded , say by $M>0$
$$
\left| \int_{C(\theta)}h(z)dz \right|\leq M\cdot long(C(\theta))= M\cdot r(\theta_2-\theta_1)\underset{ r \to 0}{\longrightarrow 0}
$$
Then we have proved that 
$$
\lim_{r \to 0}\int_{C}f(z)dz =ib_1(\theta_2-\theta_1) + 0
$$
However, since 
$$
b_1=\text{Res}(f,a)=\lim_{z \to a}(z-a)f(z)=\lambda
$$
the claim follows

Comment: One query. How do we know that $a$ is pole of $f$ ?

Comment: @Anjan3  Since $\lambda \neq \infty$ and $\lambda = \lim_{z\to a} (z-a)f(z)$, this precisely means that $a$ is a simple pole of $f$. Do you see it now? if anything else is not clear please let me know.

Comment: actually that is what my confusion. Does that follow from definition that $\lim\limits_{z\rightarrow a} (z-a)f(z)\neq 0$, a becomes a pole for $f(z)$ ?

Comment: @Anjan3 Yes it follows. To prove it, take the Laurent expansion of $f$ about $z=a$, $f(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n (z-a)^n$, thus since $\lambda \neq 0, \infty $, 
$$
\lambda = \lim_{z \to a} (z-a) f(z) =  \lim_{z \to a} \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n (z-a)^{n+1} = \lim_{z \to a} \sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1} a_n (z-a)^{n+1} + 0
$$
and hence, $a_n=0$ for all $n<-1$ and $a_{-1}=\lambda$. Therefore 
$$
f(z)=\frac{\lambda}{z-a} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n(z-a)^n
$$
which gives indeed that $z=a$ is a simple pole of $f$.

Comment: wonderful. everything is now clear to me; thanks a lot for ur kind help

Comment: Great !! Glad I could help !

Comment: @AlonsoDelfín is this a particular case of the proof you did? If $f(z)$ is continuous in the region $\vert z\vert\ge R_0, 0\le arg(z)\le\alpha (0<\alpha\le 2\pi)$ and the limit $\lim_{z\to \infty}zf(z)=A$ exist, then $\lim_{R\to\infty} \int_{T_R} f(z)dz=iA\alpha,$ where $T_R$ is the arc of the circle $\vert z\vert=R,$ which  lies in the given region traversed in the positive direction with respect to the coordinate origin.

Comment: @AnneliseToft Yes it is as long as you mean $R \to 0$ instead of $R \to \infty$ and also my proof uses that $f$ is holomorphic around $a$, in your case $a=0$.

Comment: hmm I think it's not a particular case then because I don't have $R \to 0$ 

Comment: @AnneliseToft However, you do have that $\lim_{z \to \infty} zf(z)$ exists. So you can put instead $a=\infty$ and you function has a pole at infinity. You'll need to fill in some details but the idea is the same.

Comment: ok, I'll try to make the proof.

Comment: @AnneliseToft Recall that definition of pole at $\infty$ is: $f$ has a pole at $\infty$ if when $g(z):=f(1/z)$ has a pole at $z=0$. Now use my proof.

Comment: ok so fist I should say: Let $a= \infty $, then $f $ has a pole at $\infty$. Thus, by definition of pole at $\infty, g(z) $ has a pole at $z=0$. And then do I follow your proof using the $g$ function? and when I return to the $f$ function?

Comment: @AnneliseToft I think that essentially you will have something like $$ iA\alpha =\lim_{r \to 0} \int_{C_r} g(w) dw = \lim_{R\to \infty } \int_{T_R} f(z) dz $$ where $z=1/w$ and $R=1/r$.

Comment: and then the only thing I have to change in your proof is $f$ by $g$, right?

Comment: @AnneliseToft Yeah that's for the first equality. For the second one you probably need to be more careful and work the details.

Comment: yep that's right