# Moving limit inside a contour integral

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

I'm trying to compute this integral as part of a larger problem I'm working on. 
I'm trying to solve the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx$ and to do it I'm using the method where you integrate the function $f(z) = \frac{e^{iz}}{z}$ around the indented semicircle contour.

The part that I'm working on right now is that I need to do the integral for a small half circle of radius $\epsilon$.

My path is $z(t) = \epsilon e^{it}$ for $t \in [-\pi,0]$. Thus $z'(t) = i\epsilon e^{it}$

Then the integral along the contour is

$$\int_{-\pi}^0 \frac{e^{i\epsilon e^{it}}}{\epsilon e^{it}}i\epsilon e^{it}dt = i \int_{-\pi}^0 e^{i \epsilon e^{it}}dt$$

I know the answer I'm supposed to get for this piece is $-\pi i$, and it seems like all I have to do is take the limit as $\epsilon \to 0$, but I'm not sure if I can do the following

$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}  i \int_{-\pi}^0 e^{i \epsilon e^{it}}dt =  i \int_{-\pi}^0 \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} e^{i \epsilon e^{it}}dt$$

Comment: Take a look at this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1319991/how-to-establish-lim-limits-r-rightarrow-0-int-c-fzdz-i-lambda-theta-2-t/1320015#1320015) and note that in your case $\theta_2-\theta_1=\pi$, with that you do not need to worry about the limit.